# How Windows Decides to show the screensave

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, screensaver

Windows has an internal mechanism that decides when to show the screensaver (or shut the screen off) by checking for user interactivity and other tasks (someone's watching a video, etc.).

Is there an Win API that allows me to ask whether or not the user is active, or when was the last time they were active?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called the "idle timer".  You can get its value by pinvoking [CallNtPowerInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), asking for SystemPowerInformation.  The returned SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION.TimeRemaining field tells you how much time is left on the idle timer.  The SystemExecutionState request tells you if any thread has called SetThreadExecutionState() to stop the timer, as is done by apps that show videos.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class PowerInfo {
    public static int GetIdleTimeRemaining() {
        var info = new SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION();
        int ret = GetSystemPowerInformation(SystemPowerInformation, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out info, Marshal.SizeOf(info));
        if (ret != 0) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        return info.TimeRemaining;
    }

    public static int GetExecutionState() {
        int state = 0;
        int ret = GetSystemExecutionState(SystemExecutionState, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out state, 4);
        if (ret != 0) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        return state;
    }

    private struct SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION {
        public int MaxIdlenessAllowed;
        public int Idleness;
        public int TimeRemaining;
        public byte CoolingMode;
    }
    private const int SystemPowerInformation = 12;
    private const int SystemExecutionState = 16;
    [DllImport("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint = "CallNtPowerInformation", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetSystemPowerInformation(int level, IntPtr inpbuf, int inpbuflen, out SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION info, int outbuflen);
    [DllImport("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint = "CallNtPowerInformation", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetSystemExecutionState(int level, IntPtr inpbuf, int inpbuflen, out int state, int outbuflen);

}
```

Comment: The pinvoke website doesnt offer a SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION c# implementation and mine seems to produce invalid values.  can you please update your answer with a sample implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which returns a structure containing the tick count from the last user input, one tick being 1ms. You can then compare this to the value returend by [Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) to get the elapsed time in milliseconds since the last user input.

A P/Invoke definition for this function is available here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo

Be aware though, that the tick value returned by `GetLastInputInfo` wraps back to zero just short of 50 days, but `Environment.TickCount` wraps just short of 25 days, due to the value returned by `GetLastInputInfo` being an unsigned int, and TickCount being signed. In most cases this probably won't be much of an issue, but it is worth keeping in mind that there might occasionally be somewhat odd behavior, on the order of once a month.

Comment: The GetLastInputInfo is great, but it doesnt take in account applications that report as activity. for instance - when you watch a movie in Media Player you wont get into screensaver as long as the movie is playing, but the GetLastInputInfo wont show that

Comment: Certain applications blocking the screensaver appears to be handled by responding to a windows message (`WM_SYSCOMMAND` with a `wParam` of `SC_SCREENSAVE`), instead of letting the default handler do it. I can't think of any good way of using this mechanism from outside of the OS.